# Suspicious MBR at sector 0, is there a way to fix it?

Tags: macos, boot, partitioning, multi-boot, boot-camp

I've just reinstalled Sierra after a partition resize nightmare. I wiped and restored from Time Machine and repartitioned again but haven't reinstalled Windows yet.

As seen below there is a suspicious MBR at sector 0. Is there a way to fix it?

[image: As shown here]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a hybrid MBR. It's necessary to boot Windows in BIOS mode, but if you plan to install Windows 8 or 10 in EFI mode, you need to replace the hybrid MBR with a legal protective MBR. You can do this with my [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`)](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) program:

1. Launch `gdisk` on the disk (`sudo gdisk /dev/disk0` in your case).
2. Type `x` to enter experts' mode.
3. Type `n` to create a new protective MBR.
4. Type 'w` to save your changes.
5. Type `y` to confirm that you want to save the changes.

Comment: To the anonymous editor which made a suggested edit that indicated EFI mode is required to be enabled if you want to run Windows 8 or Windows 10.  You are wrong.  Hopefully you don’t go around spreading this information, because it to put it simply, false information that confuses new Windows users.

Comment: This just saved me a lengthy re-install and re-setup of a machine that got damaged during a partition resize. THANKS!

Comment: Worked for me too!  The above steps immediately fixed my issue where Windows would no longer boot after I resized its partition.  Rod you're awesome.